# Finding the Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

the solution from my teacher is as follows;

[image]

My question is, for $0 \le x \le 1$, why do we have

[image]

instead of just having [image] ?

Does it have something to do with the discontinuity of the density function?

Comment: Because $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)\,\mathrm dt$ which is $\int_{-1}^0 (-t)\,\mathrm dt +\int_0^x t\,\mathrm dt$ for $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a picture helps. For $x$ between $0$ and $1$, $F(x)$ corresponds to the area (in grey) under the graph of $f$ (in red):

[image: intregral]

Where the area to the left of the vertical axis corresponds to $\int_{-1}^0 f(t) \ dt$, and the area to the right corresponds to $\int_{0}^x f(t) \ dt$.

Hence $F(x)=\int_{-1}^0 f(t) \ dt+\int_{0}^x f(t) \ dt=\int_{-1}^0 -t \ dt+\int_{0}^x t \ dt$.

**Edit.**

The pdf is defined piecewise as follows:
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & t\in(-\infty,-1) \\
      -t & t\in(-1,0)\\
      t & t\in (0,1)\\
      0 & t\in (1, +\infty)
   \end{cases}
$$

And the CDF is defined as
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\ dt$$

If $x\in (0,1)$, we can split this integral to get
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(t)\ dt +\int_{-1}^{0} f(t)\ dt +\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\ dt $$

Now, substituting for $f(t)$ using the above definition, this becomes

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} 0\ dt +\int_{-1}^{0} -t\ dt +\int_{0}^{x} t\ dt $$

where the first of the three integrals is just 0, and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks! but why does it correspond to the graph from $-1$ to $x$? for the second pdf, it is mentioned that x is between $0$ and $1$, not between $-1$ an $1$. I already found the CDF for $x$ between $-1$ and $0$, but it seems like we are calculating the CDF for $x$ between $-1$ and $0$ again......

Comment: $x$ is indeed between $0$ and $1$, but we are not integrating with respect to $x$, we are integrating with respect to $t$. The value of $x$ only determines the upper limit of the integral, and $F(x)$ is the integral **from -∞** to $x$, so we must consider the area under the pdf from $-\infty$ to $x$. Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused. if we take the area under the $pdf$ from $−∞$ to $x$, why don't we use this as the lower and upper limit?

Comment: We do! But the pdf is defined piecewise, i.e. it takes different expressions on each of the four intervals: $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,+\infty)$. We can't fit all those expressions in the same integral, so we split the integral up in four parts.

Comment: @FarahFai: I edited my answer. Think of the pdf as a function of $t$, not of $x$.